# Sonar is not executing unit test while executing mvn sonar:sonar -Pjs

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am having a **javascript application**, In which I want to do code validation with coverage reports using sonar. While executing **mvn sonar:sonar -Pjs** with **SonarQube version: 3.5.1**, It is **not executing js unit test**.

When I tried the same application with Sonar version: 3.3.1. It is executing js unit test and report is displayed with unit test and coverage **(Works great)**.

What is wrong with SonarQube version: 3.5.1 ? Am i missing anything ?

I have specified the console log of both sonar execution with the command **mvn sonar:sonar -Pjs**

**Logs : 
SonarQube version: 3.5.1**

```
[INFO] [13:35:18.697] Compare over 5 days (2013-09-28, analysis of 2013-10-03 13:27:35.255)
[INFO] [13:35:18.706] Compare over 30 days (2013-09-03, analysis of 2013-10-03 13:27:35.255)
[INFO] [13:35:18.738] Profile: Sonar way
[INFO] [13:35:19.139] Base dir: /Users/users/mvnsonarsonarRes
[INFO] [13:35:19.140] Working dir: /Users/users/mvnsonarsonarRes/target/sonar
[INFO] [13:35:19.140] Source dirs: /Users/users/mvnsonarsonarRes/src/main/webapp/js
[INFO] [13:35:19.140] Test dirs: /Users/users/mvnsonarsonarRes/src/test/webapp
[INFO] [13:35:19.140] Binary dirs: /Users/users/mvnsonarsonarRes/target/classes
```

**Sonar version: 3.3.1**

```
[INFO] [13:09:38.781] Compare over 5 days (2013-09-28)
[INFO] [13:09:38.781] Compare over 30 days (2013-09-03)
[INFO] [13:09:39.218] Execute maven plugin jstest-maven-plugin...
[INFO] [13:09:39.218] Execute net.awired.jstest:jstest-maven-plugin:1.0:test...
-------------------------------------------------------
 J S   T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Run suite: Login, Agent: emulator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10 ms
Results :
Run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 435ms, Coverage : 100%, Agent: emulator
[INFO] For total coverage check with sonar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ---------------------

[INFO] [13:10:24.750] Execute net.awired.jstest:jstest-maven-plugin:1.0:test done: 45532 ms
[INFO] [13:10:24.750] Execute maven plugin jstest-maven-plugin done: 45532 ms
[INFO] [13:10:24.750] Initializer JsTestMavenInitializer...
[INFO] [13:10:24.750] Initializer JsTestMavenInitializer done: 0 ms
[INFO] [13:10:24.750] Initializer ProjectFileSystemLogger...
```

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: What does your `js` profile look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be two problems. SonarQube requires the build and the sonar run to be two separate maven calls. See [sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) (very bottom of the page).

Our setup was as follows:

```
mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

This resulted still in no code coverage, exactly like your reported problem. This was caused by the option "-Dmaven.test.skip=true". This resulted in the test code not being compiled and therefore not run during the sonar run, see [maven](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html).

Our code coverage was back again after changing this to:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
mvn sonar:sonar
```